# What is the ___mac_get_pid symbol in a node profile?

Tags: c++, node.js, pid

I am profiling some multi-process nodejs code run on OSX.

I'm seeing:

```
[C++]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  23398   63.6%   63.8%  ___mac_get_pid
```

What is `___mac_get_pid`? It's name is certainly suggestive that it's some code that "gets a PID on a Mac", but the time seems excessive.

Googling has provided nothing useful.

Comment: @closevoter can you indicate your concerns about this question? It's a legitimate question that I'm seeking and answer to and I'd love to improve it, if possible.

Comment: Dancrumb, What is your profiler and how did you start it. Is there any profiler capable of recording callstack? Or try to stop the application several times in debugger (gdb/lldb) and check backtrace when you hit the `__mac_get_pid` to know who did call it. What is your OS and what does your application, is there process listing functions? Which libraries do you use?

Comment: Dancrumb, do you have other functions listed in the profile? Can you post more parts of profile, both C/C++ and node functions? Some of them may give hints about ___mac_get_pid; possibly it is connected to waiting for some processes/threads and/or connections (or may be some timeout near this). Which libraries/patterns do you use to connect multiple processes together and to exchange messages? Do you have sort nodejs example to reproduce the situation? What are versions of OSX/macOS and nodejs?

Comment: @osgx that's all probably going way beyond the scope of this particular question. For your edification, this is a nodejs application on OSX that is using the native node `child_process` functions to spawn and then communicate with a number of processes. I'm guessing these calls are associated with IPC requests.

Comment: It is beyond "what is", but it can be useful for question "why it is so high in the profile", and this question sometimes arises (one is linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456982/what-is-mac-get-pid-as-listed-in-node-profiling-logs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__mac_get_pid` is the syscall behind `mac_get_pid` library function. It is described in man page `mac_get`: http://man.cx/mac_get(3)

> mac_get_pid ..  get the label of a file, socket, socket peer or process
>   The mac_get_pid() and mac_get_proc() system calls return the process label associated with an arbitrary process ID, or the current process.
>
> Label storage for use with these calls must first be allocated and prepared using the mac_prepare(3) functions. When an application is done using a label, the memory may be returned using mac_free(3).

The "MAC" here is not Mac OS X / macOS, but [POSIX.1e](https://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=posix1e)'s [Mandatory Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) ("was introduced in FreeBSD 5.0 as part of the [TrustedBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrustedBSD) Project"). The `mac_get_pid` is [implemented in macOS/Dawrin/XNU](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/security/mac_base.c?v=xnu-2050.18.24#L1298) as "Extended non-POSIX.1e interfaces".

Possibly there is some methods in used nodejs libraries which try to do detailed work with process lists (like ps/top), but they were unable to limit rate of their requests. Getting several stacktraces with `mac_get_pid` either with profiler (not [v8 profiler](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/V8-Profiler) which stacktraces only [js](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack-Trace-API), but some external profiler attached to nodejs process) or with debugger (gdb/lldb) by manual stopping and checking backtrace until you find who calls `mac_get_pid` (continue and stop again when you are not in `mac_get_pid`) is the needed step to find out who did call it.

Comment: 2003 paper on TrustedBSD design: http://www.trustedbsd.org/trustedbsd-usenix2003freenix.pdf "The TrustedBSD MAC Framework: Extensible Kernel Access Control for FreeBSD 5.0": "*...  label management
library and system calls, which allow applications to
deal with MAC labels and elements in an abstract manner Retrieve the label of current or arbitrary process;
set the current process label. mac_get_pid()*". MAC management may be needed for login / authorization management too...