# What is __mac_get_pid as listed in node profiling logs?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, profiling

I'm running a server locally with `node --prof` and sending a get request to one of my endpoints. When I look at the processed v8.log I see

```
[C++]:
     ticks  total  nonlib   name
     336   25.7%   25.8%  ___mac_get_pid
```

What is `___mac_get_pid` and why would it be using up such a large percentage of CPU time?

For reference, this is an express server. The endpoint being hit responds to a post request that has JSON in the body. Once hit, the server makes a few calls to 3rd party APIs and responds with JSON. Data is being stored and retrieved from a Mongo db that is hosted elsewhere. The server itself is being run on macOS.

Let me know if there's anything I could clarify!

Comment: Are you using `cluster` or `child_process`?